# Xamarin: [Failure] Could not find file designtime\Resource.Designer.cs

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

While Building a Xamarin Solution

This error appears on the Build of the Android project:

> [Failure] Could not find file designtime\Resource.Designer.cs

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the **.csproj** and find

```
<AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
```

replace with:

```
<MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
<AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
<AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
```

Source: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13339/resource-designer-cs-not-regenerated#latest

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

1) Go to Project folder's Properties -> (Uncheck the Read only box) -> (Check apply to folders & sub folders)

2) Reopen and build the project.

the above solution worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the MainActivity.cs Build Action property as 'none' instead of 'compile'. I Hope this will resolve your problem, it worked for me.